# Is it possible to paginate Mysql query results in a 5 by 5 grid per page using PHP PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, pagination

I want to query a database of urls to images and then display them using php. So far I haven't been able to find any examples without using javascript (dont want to use since it loads all the images on the same page and the javascript controls just what you see).

Other pagination examples just simply don't allow you to output the results like this....

```
image1 image2 image3 image4 image5
image6 image7 image8 image9 image10

1 2 3 4 5 Next
```

...without doing away with pagination via php and having to hardcode the pagination. Which doesn't make much sense because the images may be more or less at any given time.

Anyone know if this is possible?

For example...

In this script, the loop can only control the amount of records shown per page. I need to be able to break the td after a specified number of records have been output.

```
<?php

require_once'connect.php';
$query = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table");
$rows = $query->fetchColumn();
$items_per_page = 25;
$last_page = $rows/$items_per_page;

if(isset($_GET['p']) && ctype_digit($_GET['p']) && $_GET['p'] > 0) {
    $page = $_GET['p'];
}
else {
    $page = '1';
}

if($page > $last_page) {
    $page = $last_page;
}

$page_controls = '<p class="page_controls">';
$start = ($page -1) * $items_per_page;

if($items_per_page > $rows) {
    $page_controls .= '<span>1</span>';
}
else {
    if($page > 1) {
        $prev = $page - 1;
        $page_controls .= '<a href="?p='. $prev .'">Prev</a>';

        for($i = ($page - 3); $i < $page; $i++) {
            if($i > 0) {
                $page_controls .= '<a href="?p=' . $i .'">' . $i . '</a>';
            }
        }
    }

$page_controls .= '<span>'. $page .'</span>';

if($page < $last_page) {
    for($i = $page+1; $i <= $last_page; $i++) {
        $page_controls .= '<a href="?p=' . $i . '">' . $i . '</a>';
            if($i >= $page+3) {
                break;
            }
    }

    $next = $page + 1;
    $page_controls .= '<a href="?p=' . $next . '">Next</a>';
    }
}

$page_controls .= '</p>';

$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table limit ?, ?");
$query->bindParam(1, $start, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->bindParam(2, $items_per_page, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->execute();

echo '<table>';

$cols = 5;

foreach($query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $data) {


    echo '<tr>
    <td><a href="' . $data['url'] . '"><img src="' . $data['image_url'] . '"  width=200 height=100></a></td>
    </tr>';

}

echo '</table>';

echo $page_controls;

?>
```

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Just maintain a count in your foreach loop. When count = 5 output a new `<tr>`

Comment: On the webpage, just use `float` or `inline-block` to style the items, and let them wrap. As long as you set the widths of the items and the container appropriately, you will get five items per row; then your php code can concentrate on just getting 25 items, without having to worry about the layout.

Comment: there's nothing special about this. for a 5x5 grid, you'd get 25 records per page. How you display those 25 records on a page has NOTHING to do with "pagination". pagination determines WHICH set of 25 records you get.

Comment: Marc B and Simba, I agree with your statements. Thank you for keeping things in perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Someone posted a solution earlier but then deleted it, so I can't give proper credit. However, here it is with a small modification that completes my question...

```
echo '<table>';

$cols = 5;

foreach($query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $cnt => $data) {
    if ( $cnt % $cols == 0 ) {
        echo '<tr>';
    }

    echo '<td><a href="<' . $data['url'] . '"><img src="' . $data['image_url'] . '"></a></td>
    ';

    if (  $cnt % $cols == 5 ) {
        echo '</tr>';
    }    
    $cnt++;
}

echo '</table>';
```

Overall, I agree it is best to control the layout of the images with CSS though. If you prefer that then the previous code is best.